# Spring MockMvc trimming parameter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, integration-testing, mockmvc

I have run into a problem that has me stumped. I am running the latest version of Spring and JUnit. I was experimenting with the MockMvc and Spring integration test classes in order to see if it would fit my companies needs and it was working well, until I tried to submit a request for that contained a @PathVariable which is a version number in the url.

Pom;

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <groupId>asd</groupId>
  <artifactId>asd</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>asd</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Example Controller;
    import junit.framework.Assert;

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/example/appVersion/{applicationVersion}")
    public @ResponseBody void example(@PathVariable("applicationVersion") String applicationVersion) {

        if (!"1.0.0.0".equals(applicationVersion)) {
            Assert.fail("I needed to be 1.0.0.0");
        }

    }
}
```

Test Class;

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:appContext.xml")
@WebIntegrationTest
public class ExampleProblem {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String url = "/example/appVersion/1.0.0.0";
        // String url = "/example/appVersion/{applicationVersion}";

        //@formatter:off
        MvcResult result =  webAppContextSetup(context)
        .build()
        .perform(
            get(url)
//                              get(url, "1.0.0.0")
            .accept("application/json")
        ).andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().is(200))
        .andReturn();
        //@formatter:on

        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

My appContext.xml file only contains this line (other than the initial beans tag and end tag);

```
<context:component-scan base-package="asd" />
```

When I view the request coming into my example controller, I can see with the debugger it says /example/appVersion/1.0.0.0 but the path variable is being set to "1.0.0" always. It appears the last .0 is always being dropped because if I pass in "1.0.0.0.0" it trims to the expected "1.0.0.0".

Any insight into what may be causing this or what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Spring interprets the last dot (.) and following characters as a file extension.

In order to fix this, you need to tell Spring that the parameter expects dot characters by adding **":.+"** to the end of the controller parameter.
So the annotation now looks like this;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/appVersion/{applicationVersion:.+}")
```